# How to fix the mistake of displaying the preloader

Tags: html, css

I try to fix any mistakes of displaying the preloader. When I try to upload this page, the preloader works endlessly. It's spinning nonstop.
Please help.

```
<script>
document.body.onload = function(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        var preloader=document.getElementById("page-preloader");
        if (!preloader.classList.contains('done')) {
            preloader.classList.add('done');
        }
    }, 1000);
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share the css code for `.done` please?

Answer (score 1):

It's working, it's add class done, when preloader done it's loading, but the problem is that.

Please check css, if .done class is hide itself after load or please add.

```
.done
{
display:none;
}
```